# Convert JSON array to flatfile using VB.NET

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, parsing, serialization

I realise there are a lot of questions out there relating to working with JSON but i haven't yet been able to find anything yet that has helped work this out.

To Sum:

- I am accessing a JSON response via a webservice (i cannot edit the
  json structure)
- I am working in VB.NET (and frustratingly inexperienced, please don't throw C# examples at me)
- I need to output the entire json response ultimately as a csv but help to even access values within the json would be really helpful

My current deserialization code is this, where wrString is my json

```
Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim rawdata = js.DeserializeObject(wrString)
Dim recs As List( Of TaxonObservation) = CType(rawdata, List(Of TaxonObservation))
MsgBox(recs(0).siteName)
```

but this throws the error

`unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'`

I think the json is an array of objects (but this could be my mistake?). It looks like this

```
"[{"observationID":260810677,"fullVersion":false,"datasetKey":"GA000144","surveyKey":"772","sampleKey":"772-SAMPLE","observationKey":"8048603","siteKey":"NBN-SITE-GA000144-18338220","siteName":"Court Hey Park","featureID":1410645,"location":"SJ417900","resolution":"100m","taxonVersionKey":"NBNSYS0000022280","pTaxonVersionKey":"NBNSYS0000022280","pTaxonName":"Rhytidiadelphus squarrosus","pTaxonAuthority":"(Hedw.) Warnst.","startDate":"2010-09-06","endDate":"2010-09-06","recorder":"Deed, B.","sensitive":false,"absence":false,"publicAttribute":false,"dateTypekey":"D "},{"observationID":260830853,"fullVersion":false,"datasetKey":"GA000144","surveyKey":"772","sampleKey":"772-SAMPLE","observationKey":"8048619","siteKey":"NBN-SITE-GA000144-18338223","siteName":"Court Hey Park","featureID":1410645,"location":"SJ417900","resolution":"100m","taxonVersionKey":"NBNSYS0000036189","pTaxonVersionKey":"NBNSYS0000036189","pTaxonName":"Ceratodon purpureus","pTaxonAuthority":"(Hedw.) Brid.","startDate":"2010-09-30","endDate":"2010-09-30","recorder":"Deed, B.","sensitive":false,"absence":false,"publicAttribute":false,"dateTypekey":"D "}]"
```

My class is this

```
Public Class TaxonObservation
Public Property observationID As Integer
Public Property fullVersion As Boolean
Public Property datasetKey As String
Public Property surveyKey As String
Public Property sampleKey As String
Public Property observationKey As String
Public Property siteKey As String
Public Property siteName As String
Public Property featureID As Integer
Public Property location As String
Public Property resolution As String
Public Property taxonVersionKey As String
Public Property pTaxonVersionKey As String
Public Property pTaxonName As String
Public Property pTaxonAuthority As String
Public Property startDate As String
Public Property endDate As String
Public Property recorder As String
Public Property sensitive As Boolean
Public Property absence As Boolean
Public Property dateTypekey As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the generic [`Deserialize(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead of `DeserializeObject`:

```
Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim recs As List(Of TaxonObservation) = js.Deserialize(Of List(Of TaxonObservation))(wrString)
MsgBox(recs(0).siteName)
```